# C++ Integer Concatenation

Tags: c++, binary, concatenation

I have an integer in C++, and three variables. I want to put the first binary digit of it into the first variable, the second into the second and the rest into the third.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: "first binary digit" is ambiguous.  do you mean least significant or most significant?

Comment: most significant bit for a 32-bit unsigned int x would be something like: msb = (1 << 31) & x

Comment: Thanks, then how to the get the second-most significant bit?

Comment: (I fail at coding in comments...)

Comment: @Tring Hmm... don't know... maybe **using 30 instead of 31**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 32 bit ints:

```
unsigned int val = ...;
unsigned int a, b, c;

a = val & (1U << 31); // = 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
b = val & (1U << 30); // = 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c = val & 0x3fffffff; // = 00111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bit like a coding homework to me. Despite what digit you want, basic idea is to divide this variable with 1, 10, 100, etc and keep the result as interger, then get its remainder by dividing it further w/ 10. *EXAMPLE: 578/10 -> 57.8 -> 57 -> 57%10 -> 7*.

For the coding just DIY.

Comment: Mod / div is not the way to do this.  For powers of 2, you want and and shift.  For individual bits, you want to mask.

Comment: oh the binary digit...sry my first post bloops..XD

Comment: Any competent compiler knows how to deal with division and mod by 2. There's no need to hand optimize it. The only reason to choose one way over the other is readability.

Comment: If you're actually interested in bits, it's better to deal in the bit domain by using bit operations.  division and mod are for arithmetic.  Not to mention, division by 2 gets the LSB not the MSB.